# I am getting this error "Error when enabling iframe communication" when try to run accessibility script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, accessibility, deque, axe

```
public void anyAccessibilityWithCustomReport() throws InterruptedException {
       
    Results axeResult = new AxeBuilder().disableIframeTesting().analyze(driver);
    
    Assertions.assertTrue(axeResult.violationFree(), buildCustomReport(axeResult));
}
```

The error is on this line.

```
Results axeResult = new AxeBuilder().analyze(driver);
```

And the error says the following.

```
Error when enabling iframe communication
```

I am using the above code, but sometimes my test cases become quite flaky. When that happens, I get the above error. I am using the latest version of axe core 4.7.0 . Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to remove this error?

Comment: The only way to save myself from this error is disableIframeTesting() .so please tell me the solution with out disableIframeTesting().

Comment: Results axeResult = new AxeBuilder().analyze(driver);
This line gives me below error  "Error when enabling iframe communication"